# О написании статей и копирайтинге

Tags: значение-слов, заимствования

Честно говоря, не люблю англицизмы. А сейчас очень модным стало слово "копирайтинг". Объясните мне, пожалуйста, что это такое и чем это отличается (и отличается ли) от нормального русского написания статей?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Отличается. Услышите где-нибудь "копирайтинг", "контент-менеджер", "арт-директор" - бегите оттуда. В правильном, годном производственном процессе все виды деятельности можно описать нормальными русскими словами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Копирайтинг - это написание именно рекламных (продающих) статей. 
Цель - описать товар/услугу так, чтобы его/ее купили. 
   Просто написание статей - это немного другое

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, копирайтинг — профессиональная деятельность по написанию рекламных и презентационных текстов. И начинался он, похоже, с окон РОСТА:-))

Answer (score 1):

Копирайтинг - это написание текстов на заказ. Тексты не обязательно носят коммерческий характер (вплоть до художественного произведения, или научной работы), но  как правило это та или иная разновидность рекламы.

От просто написания текста, копирайтинг отличают направленность на коммерческую реализацию созданного материала.

Словари пока дают определение, только как рекламный текст, но это не соответствует широте употребления этого неологизма.